# Is there a better way of writing this code to avoid redundancy?

Tags: perl

I have a segment of code in a program, which accepts GNU style input from a pipe (which is a list of file names). If STDIN does not contain data, I need to accept input from a predetermined text file containing file names.

I find myself needing to write redundant code. Is it possible to simplify this bit of code to avoid redundancy?

```
sub downloadlinkgen {
    my $fh;
    print "Printing links\n";
    if ($getfilelist==1) {
        open $fh, '<', "fuzzyfile" or die $!;
        while (<$fh>) {
            chomp ($_);     
            (my $fname,my $path, my $suffix) = fileparse($_);
            my ($name, $ext) = $fname =~ /(.*)\.(.*)/;      
            my $newfile=$path.$name.".$ext";
            $newfile =~ s/\s/%20/g; 
            $newfile =~ s/\/root/http:\/\/myip/;        
            print $newfile."\n";        
        }
    } else {        
        while (<>) {
            chomp ($_);     
            (my $fname,my $path, my $suffix) = fileparse($_);
            my ($name, $ext) = $fname =~ /(.*)\.(.*)/;      
            my $newfile=$path.$name.".$ext";
            $newfile =~ s/\s/%20/g; 
            $newfile =~ s/\/root/http:\/\/myip/;        
            print $newfile."\n";        
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, just make the default ARGV filehandle open the file:

```
sub downloadlinkgen {
    @ARGV = 'fuzzyfile' if $getfilelist == 1;
    print "Printing links\n";
    while (<>) {
        chomp ($_);     
        (my $fname,my $path, my $suffix) = fileparse($_);
        my ($name, $ext) = $fname =~ /(.*)\.(.*)/;      
        my $newfile=$path.$name.".$ext";
        $newfile =~ s/\s/%20/g; 
        $newfile =~ s/\/root/http:\/\/myip/;        
        print $newfile."\n";        
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. I wouldn't use it in a large program. I usually process @ARGV at the start of the script. YMMV.

Answer (score 2):

```
sub downloadlinkgen {

  # default file handle  
  my $fh = \*ARGV;
  print "Printing links\n";
  if ($getfilelist==1) {
    open $fh, '<', "fuzzyfile" or die $!;
  }

  while (<$fh>) {
    chomp ($_);   
    (my $fname,my $path, my $suffix) = fileparse($_);
    my ($name, $ext) = $fname =~ /(.*)\.(.*)/;    
    my $newfile=$path.$name.".$ext";
    $newfile =~ s/\s/%20/g; 
    $newfile =~ s/\/root/http:\/\/myip/;    
    print $newfile."\n";    
  }
}
```

From `perldoc -f readline`

> Reads from the filehandle whose typeglob is contained in EXPR (or from *ARGV if EXPR is not provided)

so `\*ARGV` is reference to file handle used when reading from `<>`, and you can use `$fh` in both cases.

Comment: What does `$fh = \*ARGV;` do?

Comment: `while (defined($getfilelist==1 ? <$fh> : <>)) {}`

Answer (score 1):

Even if you don't know about `ARGV`, you could do something simple like this:

```
sub downloadlinkgen {
    my $fh;
    print "Printing links\n";
    if ($getfilelist==1) {
        open $fh, '<', "fuzzyfile" or die $!;
        while (<$fh>) {
            process_line($_);     
        }
    } else {        
        while (<>) {
            process_line($_);       
        }
    }
}

sub process_line {
    my $line = shift;

    chomp ($line);     
    (my $fname,my $path, my $suffix) = fileparse($line);
    my ($name, $ext) = $fname =~ /(.*)\.(.*)/;      
    my $newfile=$path.$name.".$ext";
    $newfile =~ s/\s/%20/g; 
    $newfile =~ s/\/root/http:\/\/myip/;        
    print $newfile."\n";  
}
```

Comment: Yea, using another subroutine was a definite option, but I was looking for a more perl-ish way of doing things. ;)

Comment: You don't think subroutines are Perlish? :-)

Comment: Not very. It's perlish, but not a perlism. :D